# Passing values from NumericUpDown control to SQL database

Tags: sql, floating-point, double, precision

I have some field in my table formatted with four decimal places (i.e. 0.0125).

I am using a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) object in Visual Basic to collect numbers which I then want to pass to my database.

Unfortunately when I run my code I get the following error:

> Conversion from string " (CallType,ChargeCode,Destinatio" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Here is a copy of the code I am using to push the values to the database.

```
Using cmdc = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & TextBox2.Text
                             & " (CallType,
                                  ChargeCode,
                                  Destination,
                                  TariffUsed,
                                  (case when chargecode in ('" + Combobox2.text + "') then '" + NumericUpDown1.value + "'
                                  else Peak*2 end) as Peak,
                                  (case when chargecode in ('" + Combobox2.text + "') then '" + NumericUpDown2.value + "'
                                  else OffPeak*2 end) as OffPeak,
                                 (case when chargecode in ('" + Combobox2.text + "') then '" + NumericUpDown3.value + "'
                                 else Weekend*2 end) as Weekend,
                                 (case when chargecode in ('" + Combobox2.text + "') then '" + NumericUpDown4.value + "'
                                 else Setup*2 end) as Setup,
                                 (case when chargecode in ('" + Combobox2.text + "') then '" + NumericUpDown5.value + "'
                                 else MinimumCharge*2 end) as MinimumCharge,
                                 ChargeCap,
                                 InitialUnits,
                                 InitialCharge,
                                 InitialPeak,
                                 InitialOffPeak,
                                 InitialWeekend,
                                 BillingUnit,
                                 MinimumUnits,
                                 RateType
                          FROM " & ComboBox1.Text & "", con)

con.Open()
cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
End Using
End Using
```

As DOUBLE doesn't exist in SQL, I have the destination fields configured as FLOAT.

Is it possible to pass values from the NumericUpDown into my database, and if so what is the correct format?

Comment: This code has sql injection vulnerabilities.  Use parameterized values for ALL your parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks, however this is an internally used application behind a good firewall - So I do not need to be concerned with SQL injection

Comment: Good, then I will not mention that many attacks are internal or chide you on your coding practices. ;) As to your answer, have you tried a `ToString()` on the end of `value`?

Comment: Also, you dont mention which Db platform you are using.  But the syntax for an insert is usually `insert into (fields) values (values)`  I'm not sure your insert statement would succeed.

Comment: You can chide all you like - I am very new to VB, so I appreciated the pointers ;) With regards the ToString() function, in what context/syntax is that applied? I am using VB.NET and SQL Server. I have tested the SQL using the management studio, just without the text/combo varibles

Comment: I dont have a VB project in front of me right now, but if you change your code to `NumericUpDown1.value.ToString()`, it should automatically convert the double value in your updown box to a string.  Then concatenation will occur instead of addition.

Comment: For clarity, the problem you are having is c# related, not sql related.  The sql error will occur when you are able to execute this string.

Comment: You might also have more success if you set this string to a variable above this code.  That would allow you to parse it and debug is value so that you can see what its creating.

Comment: I have added the .value.ToString() - but now get " Incorrect syntax near '(' " - Is that a App Code or SQL error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51781/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-user3580480)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @Paqogomez:

The ToString() fixed the issue.

Here is the working code:

```
Using cmdc = New SqlCommand("Insert into " & TextBox2.Text & " Select CallType,ChargeCode,Destination,TariffUsed,(case when chargecode in ('" + ComboBox2.Text + "') then " + NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString() + " else Peak*2 end) as Peak,(case when chargecode in ('" + ComboBox2.Text + "') then " + NumericUpDown2.Value.ToString() + " else OffPeak*2 end) as OffPeak,(case when chargecode in ('" + ComboBox2.Text + "') then " + NumericUpDown3.Value.ToString() + " else Weekend*2 end) as Weekend,(case when chargecode in ('" + ComboBox2.Text + "') then " + NumericUpDown4.Value.ToString() + " else Setup*2 end) as Setup,(case when chargecode in ('" + ComboBox2.Text + "') then " + NumericUpDown5.Value.ToString() + " else MinimumCharge*2 end) as MinimumCharge,ChargeCap,InitialUnits,InitialCharge,InitialPeak,InitialOffPeak,InitialWeekend,BillingUnit,MinimumUnits,RateType from Daisy_March2014", con)
con.Open()
cmdc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarrif2", TextBox2.Text)
cmdc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now())
cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
End Using
End Using
```

*Use at your own risk, should really be parametized!